# ipv6 address in azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address when nic have ipv4 and ipv6 adress

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform to create a resource group. The resource group have virtual machine with a NIC having ipv4 and ipv6 address. I am trying to create a load balancer with backend address pool having ipv4,ipv6 ip address.I am able to create backend pool with ipv4 but not able to create with ipv6. I need to know how to access ipv6 address of the NIC so that I can call it in the ip_address part.

something in `ip_address = azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside[count.index].private_ip_address` need to be changed but not sure what to change.

if I add an ipv6 address statically like ip_address = "fd00:ab8:deca:4::4" I can create it, I need a dynamic way, cause I want to create multiple vm and ipv6 address I have kept as dynamic.

need to know how to point ip_address to secondary ipv6 address of a NIC dynamically

```
variable "instances" {
  default     = 2
  description = "Number of instances"
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm-outside" {
  depends_on          = [azurerm_subnet.subnets]
  name                = "${var.prefix}-xxx%{if var.instances > 1}-${count.index}%{endif}"
  count               = var.instances
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = local.rg_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "xxx-ipv4%{if var.instances > 1}-${count.index}%{endif}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnets["xxx"].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"

    primary                       = true
  }
   ip_configuration {
    name                          = "xxx-ipv6%{if var.instances > 1}-${count.index}%{endif}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnets["xxx"].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    private_ip_address_version    = "IPv6"
  }

 
}
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "backend-address-ipv4" {
  count                   = var.instances > 1 ? var.instances : 0
  name                    = "backend-address-%{if var.instances > 1}-${count.index}%{endif}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend-address-Pool[0].id
  virtual_network_id      = var.vn ? azurerm_virtual_network.vm[0].id : data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm[0].id
  ip_address              = azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside[count.index].private_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "backend-address-ipv6" {
  count                   = var.instances > 1 ? var.instances : 0
  name                    = "backend-address-ipv6-%{if var.instances > 1}-${count.index}%{endif}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend-address-Pool[0].id
  virtual_network_id      = var.vn ? azurerm_virtual_network.vm[0].id : data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm[0].id
  ip_address              = azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside[count.index+1].private_ip_address
}
```

I get below error:

```
count.index is 1
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.
```

Comment: Can you add the output when you are not hard-coding the value to the question?

Comment: updated the output.

Comment: So the VM resource has only one index, and that is `0`. The place where you want to try and work with a different index is the `private_ip_address`. My best guess is that is the place where you want to try `private_ip_address[count.index + 1]`.

Comment: Sorry, not VM but rather `vm-outside` has only index `0`. The `ip_configuration` might be providing more than one index.

Comment: Ok, so further reading about the resource shows that there are two available attributes: `private_ip_address` and `private_ip_addresses`. Try using the second one with indexing, i.e., for the IPv4 one `private_ip_addresses[count.index]` and for the IPv6 one `private_ip_addresses[count.index+1]`.

Comment: Getting this error:

│  609:   ip_address              = azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside[count.index].private_ip_addresses[count.index+1]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside is tuple with 2 elements
│     │ count.index is 1
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.

Comment: worked partially with ```ip_address              = azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside[count.index].private_ip_addresses[1]``` getting error as ```backend-address-1" already exists
│ - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" for more information.
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245643/discussion-between-pankaj-sheoran-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to make it work with this statement. Thanks to Marko  `ip_address              = azurerm_network_interface.vm-outside[count.index].private_ip_addresses[1]`